# Converting accented characters in varchar() to XML causing "illegal XML character"

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode, character-encoding, type-conversion

I have table written to by an application.  The field is varchar(max).  The data looks like xml.

```
DECLARE @poit VARCHAR(100)
SET @poit = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><test>VÍA</test>'
SELECT CONVERT(XML,@poit)
```

But (seemingly because of the UTF8; removing it works), I get this error:

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 46, illegal xml character
```

Is there a way to cleanly convert it?

I found this thread, which talks about varchar not supporting "non-ASCII characters", though obviously the I is non-unicode.  Yes, I can do this:

SELECT CONVERT(XML, REPLACE(@poit, 'encoding="utf-8"', ''))

But is that the best way?

[Why does casting a UTF-8 VARCHAR column to XML require converting to NVARCHAR and encoding change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137540/why-does-casting-a-utf-8-varchar-column-to-xml-require-converting-to-nvarchar-an)

Comment: Just few cents from me. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar#147302) answer is a great explanation why you should always use nvarchar instead of varchar.

Comment: Yes and no. In reality, for me it's normally not worth the cost (storage space, backup space, and IOPS). Yes, it'd make life simpler, but I'm already growing at 40gb/day.

Comment: @gofr1 That answer is overly simplistic and based on the very false myth that the only cost to disk is money. I wrote an article on this topic that details all of the "hidden" costs: [Disk Is Cheap! ORLY?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/data-modeling/71725/) (that site does require free registration in order to view their content). Also, I updated my answer below to include info about the internal optimization of the `XML`, type and when using it actually takes up less space than using `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing the datatype of your `@poit` variable from `VARCHAR(100)` to `NVARCHAR(100)`.  Then replace the utf-8 encoding with utf-16 so your code would look something like:

```
    DECLARE @poit NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @poit = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><test>VÍA</test>'
    SELECT CONVERT(XML,REPLACE(@poit, 'utf-8', 'utf-16'))
```

As long as you're not calling the conversion with the replace in it in a SELECT that returns oodles of results, the performance should be just fine and it will get the job done.

Reference: http://xml.silmaril.ie/characters.html <- scroll down and you'll see some info as to the difference between utf-8 & utf-16.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point about using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. However, you need to carry that all the way through and prefix the literals with a capital-`N`, else you can lose data. Also, no need to replace `utf-8` with `utf-16` as UTF-16 is the only encoding that `NVARCHAR` data could be anyway ;-). If interested, I have a full explanation in my answer :).

Answer (score 4):

<sup>**<TL;DR>** If you just want the answer without the full explanation, scroll down to the "Conclusion". But, you really should take a moment to read the explanation 😸 **</TL;DR>**</sup>

There are a few things going on here:

1. The `encoding=` attribute of the `<xml>` element is used to denote how the underlying bytes of the XML document are to be interpreted. If the document within the string literal is correct, then there is no need to have the `encoding` attribute. If there are characters that are incorrect, then the `encoding` attribute can remain as it will inform the XML conversion on what those characters were originally.
2. UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding, yet you have the variable and literal as `VARCHAR` data, not `NVARCHAR` (which also requires prefixing the string literal with a capital-`N`). By using `VARCHAR` and no `N`-prefix, if there were any characters in the XML document that couldn't fit into the Code Page denoted by the default Collation of whatever database you are in when executing this query, you would have already lost those characters (even if you can see them on screen, they wouldn't be correct in the `VARCHAR` variable, or if you did a simple `SELECT` of that literal).
3. Windows (and .NET, SQL Server, etc) use UTF-16 Little Endian. The `Í` character, [Latin Capital Letter I with Acute](http://unicode-table.com/en/00CD/), exists in both Code Page 1252 *and* UTF-16LE as value 205 (e.g. `SELECT ASCII('Í'), CHAR(205);` ), which is why it works when you remove the `encoding="utf-8"` and why you didn't "lose" that character by placing it in a `VARCHAR` literal and variable. HOWEVER, as shown on that linked page, the byte sequence in the UTF-8 encoding is 195, 141 (yes, two bytes). Meaning, that character, if it truly was UTF-8 encoded, would not appear to be that character when placed into a UTF-16LE environment.

   The XML conversion looks at that character's byte value of 205 (single byte since it is currently VARCHAR data) and tries to provide the UTF-16LE equivalent of what *that* sequence is in UTF-8. Except 205 by itself doesn't exist in UTF-8. So you need to add in the next character which is a capital-"A" which has a value of 65. While there are two-byte sequences in UTF-8, none of them are 205, 65. This is why you get the `illegal xml character` error.
4. Since the text on screen has to be UTF-16LE, if the source really was UTF-8, then the underlying UTF-8 byte sequence would have to be converted into UTF-16LE. The underlying byte sequence of `Í` is 195, 141. So we can create that sequence out of regular ASCII characters of Code Page 1252 (since this is, again, currently VARCHAR data) by doing the following:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @poit VARCHAR(100);
   SET @poit = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>V'
                 + CHAR(195) + CHAR(141) + 'A</test>';
   SELECT CONVERT(XML, @poit);
   ```

   Returns:

   ```xml
   <test>VÍA</test>
   ```

   Data is still `VARCHAR` *and* `encoding="utf-8"` is still in the `<xml>` element!
5. If keeping the data as `VARCHAR`, then the following change of just the `encoding=` value works:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @poit VARCHAR(100);
   SET @poit = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><test>VÍA</test>';
   SELECT CONVERT(XML, @poit);
   ```

   This assumes that the source encoding really was "Windows-1252", which is Microsoft's version of Latin1_General, which is the basis of the Latin1_General collations.

   BUT, there is again no need to even specify the "encoding" if it is the same as the Code Page of the current databases's default collation as that is assumed for any VARCHAR data.
6. Finally, `XML` data in SQL Server is UTF-16LE, same as `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` (and `NTEXT`, but nobody should be using that anymore).

### CONCLUSION

1. Use a datatype of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` when working with XML as strings (not `VARCHAR`).
2. For strings that do not have any altered characters (i.e. everything looks perfect on screen), then simply remove the `encoding="utf-8"` as you are doing. There is no need to replace it with `UTF-16` as that is assumed by the very nature of the value being in an `NVARCHAR` variable or literal (i.e. a string prefixed with a capital-`N`).

---

Regarding the use of `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `XML` or even `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in order to save space, please keep in mind that the `XML` datatype is internally optimized such that element and attribute names only get stored once, in a dictionary, and hence do not have nearly as much overhead as the fully written out string version of the XML. So while the `XML` type does store strings as UTF-16LE, ***if*** the XML document has a lot of repeated element and/or attribute names, then using the `XML` type might actually result in a smaller footprint than using `VARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
DECLARE @ElementBased XML;
SET @ElementBased = (
                     SELECT * FROM master.sys.all_columns FOR XML PATH('Row')
                    );

DECLARE @AttributeBased XML;
SET @AttributeBased = (
                       SELECT * FROM master.sys.all_columns FOR XML RAW('Row')
                      );

SELECT @ElementBased AS [ElementBasedXML],
       @AttributeBased AS [AttributeBasedXML],

       DATALENGTH(@ElementBased) AS [ElementBasedXmlBytes],
       DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @ElementBased)) AS [ElementBasedVarCharBytes],
       ((DATALENGTH(@ElementBased) * 1.0) / DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @ElementBased))
               ) * 100 AS [XmlElementSizeRelativeToVarcharElementSize],

       DATALENGTH(@AttributeBased) AS [AttributeBasedXmlBytes],
       DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @AttributeBased)) AS [AttributeBasedVarCharBytes],
       ((DATALENGTH(@AttributeBased) * 1.0) /
         DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @AttributeBased))) * 100
               AS [XmlAttributeSizeRelativeToVarCharAttributeSize];
```

Returns (on my system, at least):

```
ElementBasedXmlBytes                              1717896
ElementBasedVarCharBytes                          5889081
XmlElementSizeRelativeToVarcharElementSize        29.170867237180130482100

AttributeBasedXmlBytes                            1544661
AttributeBasedVarCharBytes                        3461864
XmlAttributeSizeRelativeToVarCharAttributeSize    44.619343798600984902900
```

As you can see, for element-based XML, the `XML` datatype is 29% the size of the `VARCHAR(MAX)` version, and for the attribute-based XML, the `XML` datatype is 44% the size of the `VARCHAR(MAX)` version.

Comment: Thanks for adding that last bit about the internal optimization of repeated strings, as well as a super-complete answer!

Comment: It is a good answer, but it was waaayyy too long and I almost missed the conclusion and scrolled off to some other answer.

Comment: @nurettin Given the vast amount of misinformation and misunderstanding regarding Unicode / encodings / Collations / etc, and that most posts and answers on this topic are incorrect (to varying degrees), I would argue that this answer is very much _not_ too long as this info is very much needed. However, I do realize that there is also only so much time in the day, so I added a note at the top instructing folks to scroll to the CONCLUSION if they don't want the explanation.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky that is pretty neat