# Sql string replace issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameter in stored procedure named grouplist.
This contain  column names in comma seperated values.

for eg: **@grouplist='Class1,Class2,Class3'**

My query is

Set @Sql= 'select ' + @grouplist +' from #final

My result is

[image: Table result]

These columns contains value "ZZTotal" value. Its should be replaced with "Total" .These are dynamic columns.

I need to replace zztotal with total.

In the final output it should be like this

[image: final output]

Any help appreciated

Comment: Your question lacks any context to make it understandable. I can't tell from reading this what you are trying to do or what the problem is. You might start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Sean Lange  I have modified the question

Comment: Well the question is certainly different, sadly it isn't any more clear than it was before. I would be leery of a query with columns dynamically being selected like this. If you are stuck using dynamic sql you are going to have to jump through some serious hurdles to pull this off. You need to provide a LOT more information here. You will likely need a string splitter to rebuild your dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

There is a larger problem that is being ignored: there is most likely a reason that the text is already `ZZTotal` instead of `Total`. And that reason is most likely in order to maintain proper row ordering (i.e. keeping the totals at the bottom).

The `ZZTotal` rows are most likely being generated automatically by SQL Server via the `ROLLUP` option of the [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause. Initially, the `ROLLUP` option places `NULL` in each "group" that is being rolled-up since the string "Total" (or any string) won't fit into a column of non-string datatypes. I am guessing that the `NULL` values were replaced with `ZZTotal` via `ISNULL()` when dumping the results into `#final`.

The current problem is that if you replace the `ZZTotal` values with `Total`, then the "Total" rows will possibly not be at the bottom of that grouping, at least not for any groupings that contain strings starting with `U...`, or `Tp...`, or `Tou...`, and so on.

1. The first step is to add an [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) column to the `#final` table. You do this by changing the query that creates and populates `#final` by adding `IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS [RowNum],` as the first column of the `SELECT` statement.
2. The second step is to change the `ISNULL(column, 'ZZTotal')` of the query that populates `#final` to instead be (for Class2, for example):

   ```
   IIF(GROUPING(class2) = 0, class2, N'Total for ' + class1) AS [Class2]
   ```

   Please note the use of "class1", not "class2", at the end of `N'Total for ' + class1`.
3. The third / final step is to add `ORDER BY [RowNum]` to the end of the `Set @Sql=` statement. The final query should be something like:

   ```
   SELECT Class1, Class2, Class3 FROM #final ORDER BY [RowNum];
   ```

**Example 1: ROLLUP default behavior**

```
SELECT ss.[name] AS [SchemaName],
       so.[type_desc] AS [ObjectType],
       COUNT(*) AS [ObjectCount]
FROM [master].sys.schemas ss
INNER JOIN [master].sys.objects so
        ON so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
GROUP BY ss.[name], so.[type_desc] WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Example 2: ROLLUP with NULLs replaced in GROUPING rows**

```
SELECT IIF(GROUPING(ss.[name]) = 0, ss.[name], N'Total') AS [SchemaName],
       IIF(GROUPING(so.[type_desc]) = 0,
           so.[type_desc], 
           IIF(GROUPING(ss.[name]) = 0,
               N'Total for ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS + ss.[name],
               N'---------------------------------------->')
          ) AS [ObjectType],
       COUNT(*) AS [ObjectCount]
FROM [master].sys.schemas ss
INNER JOIN [master].sys.objects so
        ON so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
GROUP BY ss.[name], so.[type_desc] WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Example 3: Adding IDENTITY column and INTO clause to Example #2**

```
SELECT IIF(GROUPING(ss.[name]) = 0, ss.[name], N'Total') AS [SchemaName],
       IIF(GROUPING(so.[type_desc]) = 0,
           so.[type_desc], 
           IIF(GROUPING(ss.[name]) = 0,
               N'Total for ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS + ss.[name],
               N'---------------------------------------->')
          ) AS [ObjectType],
       COUNT(*) AS [ObjectCount],
       IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS [RowNum]
INTO #TempResults
FROM [master].sys.schemas ss
INNER JOIN [master].sys.objects so
        ON so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id]
GROUP BY ss.[name], so.[type_desc] WITH ROLLUP;

SELECT * FROM #TempResults ORDER BY [RowNum];
```

Comment: Nice one! That much more informative answer than mine (deleted). One *stupid* question, I haven't used group by with rollup, it always add ZZ to total automatically or this is something that you add manually?

Comment: @gofr1 No, `ROLLUP` has to use `NULL`, probably because it is the only common "value" that can be used across all datatypes. The "Total" and "ZZTotal" are manually added after the fact via `ISNULL` or `IIF` / `CASE` as I described here.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification!

Comment: @gofr1 No problem. I just updated my answer to include some example code to illustrate the behavior. Enjoy :)

Comment: @gofr1 True, and I appreciate the sentiment. Perhaps you would find the following answer interesting and of merit? ;)  [Converting accented characters in varchar() to XML causing “illegal XML character”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274521/converting-accented-characters-in-varchar-to-xml-causing-illegal-xml-characte/39922862#39922862) ?